# Is it generally a good idea to put a console client into module's __name__ == __main__ section?

Tags: python

Is it generally a good idea to put a console client into module's `if __name__ == "__main__":` section? E.g. code to setup argparser and preprocess user input.

Comment: Basically it comes down to what the program needs to do. For testing purposes it may be better to move things to a `def main()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this, a program will effectively double as a module and a script. There's nothing wrong with this *per se*. The `pdb` standard module is an example and e.g. programs that run as Windows services using `win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework` are usually done this way.

Your only concern here is if you have several scripts and/or modules, you can still tell which is which. See [Is a Scripts directory an anti-pattern in Python? If so, what's the right way to import?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26724268/is-a-scripts-directory-an-anti-pattern-in-python-if-so-whats-the-right-way-to) for a related discussion.